# SAS: how to change SAS text miner background color?

Tags: sas, sas-macro, sas-metadata

Can I change the background color of SAS text miner window. Below is snapshot of such window. How Can I change the gray to white or other color?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: This is probably a SAS tech support question.

Comment: You might have to change your Windows theme.